# How to post and take data from MySQL for specific id from android app

Tags: php, android, mysql

How to load data from MySQL for specific id. What I mean is when I click on gridview item 1 to load what I need for this item from MySQL. Currently I have

```
    $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("database");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
$resultArray = array();
while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
    $arrCol = array();
    for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
    {
        $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
    }
    array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
}

mysql_close($objConnect);

echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

This obviously load everything from that table. But what if I want when I click on list item_1 to load some query like `select * from table where clickeditem = 1` ?
I guess I must post it to the `.php` script but how?

I don't know which part of JAVA code is needed so please tell me if you need and I will post it.
Updated:
    @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
        String url = "file.php";

        JSONArray data;
        try {
            resultServer = getJSONUrl(url);
            data = new JSONArray(resultServer);

            MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
            HashMap<String, Object> map;

            for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put("id", (String)c.getString("id"));
                map.put("name", (String)c.getString("name"));
                map.put("price", (String)c.getString("price"));
                map.put("weight", (String)c.getString("weight"));

                // Thumbnail Get ImageBitmap To Bitmap
                map.put("ImagePathThum", (String)c.getString("image"));
                map.put("ImageThumBitmap", (Bitmap)loadBitmap(c.getString("image")));

                // Full (for View Full)
                map.put("ImagePathFull", (String)c.getString("image_big"));

                MyArrList.add(map);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

UPDATE with sql.

```
    $strSQL = "SELECT m.id, name, image, image_big, weight, price 
        FROM posts m 
        JOIN packet_r mr 
        ON m.id = mr.id 
        WHERE packed_id = 1";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you would indeed need to post it to the php script. And that's very easy:

```
static String url = "https://yourlink.com/database.php?clickeditem=1";
```

Then you can edit your php code like:

```
$clickeditem = $_GET['clickeditem'];
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE clickeditem = '$clickeditem'";
```

To edit this in your java code simply add:

```
"https://yourlink.com/database.php?clickeditem=" + variable;
```

to your link with the variable to be set when a specific gridview item is clicked.

Comment: Thank you for answer but I'm not sure that I understand you. I've updated my question with the part of Java where I make request to DB

Comment: added also current `sql query` so I need to get that gridview item in WHERE clause.

Comment: This `variable` in my case will be `map.put("id", (String)c.getString("id"));` but how to put it in link in JAVA part?