# how to obtain values by selected id android

Tags: php, android, mysql

The below code android code fetches data from mysql and display all the values in it that is it fetch by id. but i want to convert the code instead of fetching all data id let it just fetch selected comment_id = 3 they it will only display values of all related comment of comment _id 3

```
id             comment_id                  comment
1                   1                   love this product
2                   1                   not bad
3                   2                   too expensive
4                   2                   how much
5                   2                   too old
6                   3                   not that new
7                   5                   hate it
8                   7                   go away
9                   8                   what wrong with you
10                  4                   hi
11                  7                   hi
12                  4                   helo
13                  7                   hola
14                  4                   go away
15                  6                   nice
16                  3                   bye
```

so this is the android code

```
package com.androidjson.serverupdate_androidjsoncom;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class test2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView StudentListView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    String HttpUrl = "http://192.168.0.199/edit/AllStudentData.php";
    List<String> IdList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_all_students);

        StudentListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        new GetHttpResponse(test2.this).execute();

        //Adding ListView Item click Listener.
        StudentListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(test2.this,ShowSingleRecordActivity.class);

                // Sending ListView clicked value using intent.
                intent.putExtra("ListViewValue", IdList.get(position).toString());

                startActivity(intent);

                //Finishing current activity after open next activity.
                finish();

            }
        });
    }

    // JSON parse class started from here.
    private class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        public Context context;

        String JSonResult;

        List<Student> studentList;

        public GetHttpResponse(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {
            // Passing HTTP URL to HttpServicesClass Class.
            HttpServicesClass httpServicesClass = new HttpServicesClass(HttpUrl);
            try
            {
                httpServicesClass.ExecutePostRequest();

                if(httpServicesClass.getResponseCode() == 200)
                {
                    JSonResult = httpServicesClass.getResponse();

                    if(JSonResult != null)
                    {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                        try {
                            jsonArray = new JSONArray(JSonResult);

                            JSONObject jsonObject;

                            Student student;

                            studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                            {
                                student = new Student();

                                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                // Adding Student Id TO IdList Array.
                                IdList.add(jsonObject.getString("id").toString());

                                //Adding Student Name.
                                student.StudentName = jsonObject.getString("name").toString();

                                studentList.add(student);

                            }
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, httpServicesClass.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            StudentListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            ListAdapterClass adapter = new ListAdapterClass(studentList, context);

            StudentListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
}
```

this is my php code

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/config.php");

 $id= $_POST['id'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {

 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments where comment_id = '$id'" ;

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {


 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $tem = $row;

 $json = json_encode($tem);

 }

} else {
 echo "No Results Found.";
}
 echo $json;

$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to download all the data and filter the data in your android code but if you want to return only the data from your PHP code that you need, then you must show us your PHP code so we can give you the specific help you need.

Comment: if you can help me with a full code will be happy. am trying to implement comment in my app so i want once a product is click and the activity opens then the comment will load. comment_id is as the same as product_id in another table so once the activity open it will link the product_id and comment_id to load only comment for that product

Comment: Have uploaded the php file

Answer (score 0):

you should send id and add it to your mysql WHERE.
it can be useful:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082768/how-to-post-and-take-data-from-mysql-for-specific-id-from-android-app)

Comment: How will i pass value to listview and display all from mysql

Comment: thats what i want